# FastReport4 - Child bands inheritance

Tags: fastreport

I have this situation with child bands in my fast report4:

ColumnHeader band (this one is displaying on every page always)

Child band, let's call it ChildOne, is a child of ColumnHeader. This one is visible only on first page.

Child band, let's call it ChildTwo, is a child of ChildOne. This one must be visible on pages other than page1.

But, the problem is, ChildTwo obviously inherits the visibility property of ChildOne and is not being displayed on subsequent pages... How do I overcome this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

One possible approach is to attach child bands dynamically. You may try with these steps:

- Remove the links between bands (column header band and first child band, first child band and second child band)
- Add these links at run-time using column header band's OnBeforePrint event.

**Event handler:**

```
procedure ColumnHeader1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
   Child1.Visible := False;  
   Child2.Visible := False;  
   if (<Page#> = 1) then begin
      Child1.Visible := True;  
      ColumnHeader1.Child := Child1;                                                      
      end           
   else begin                                           
      Child2.Visible := True;  
      ColumnHeader1.Child := Child2;
   end;                
end;
```